# How to Get Android Annotations Working in Studio 0.8.2

Tags: android, android-annotations

I've been trying to get Android Annotations running my installation of Android Studio 0.8.2 and cannot get it working correctly.

Here's what I've done to get it set up...

In File > Settings > Compiler > Annotation Processors
Selected "Enable annotation processing"
Processor path set to "C:\software\android\androidannotations-3.0.1.jar;C:\software\android\androidannotations-api-3.0.1.jar"

Store Generated sources set to "Module content root"
Directories are set to "gen/aa" and "gen/aa-test"

Placed the androidannotations-3.0.1.jar file in the project's libs directory.

I can add the annotations to the files correctly, autocomplete finds all the annotations.

However, when I change the AndroidManifest.xml file to use the _ at the end of the android:name, it shows as red, and doesn't launch the app.

Then, after changing the Activity in the Launch Configurations to use the underscore, it also fails with an error.

Next steps?

```
    <activity
        android:name=".FlagActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



@EActivity
public class FlagActivity extends Activity implements
      GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
      GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got Android Annotations running on Android Studio 0.8.2.

First off, you shouldn't have to specify a specific Activity, just choose "Launch default activity". Your manifest looks fine.

What I've found is that you need to sync gradle from time to time so the BlahActivity_ can be generated.

Here is my gradle config for my app module (only the Android annotations specific configs):

```
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                mavenCentral()
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
                classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2+'
            }
        }

        apply plugin: 'android'
        apply plugin: 'android-apt'

        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }

        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

        android {

            compileSdkVersion 20
            buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.foo.androidapp"
                minSdkVersion 16
                targetSdkVersion 20
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
            }

            buildTypes {
                release {
                    runProguard false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }

            // AA: if you are going to use the spring rest template with AA
            packagingOptions {
                exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
                exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
                exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
                exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
                exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            }

            productFlavors {

                production {
                    packageName = 'com.foo.androidapp'
                }

                development {
                    packageName = 'com.foo.androidapp.dev'
                }

            }
        }

        dependencies {
            // AA imports (also enables REST support w AA)!!
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.0+'
            compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
            compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1.3'
            compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
            apt 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.0+'

        }

        apt {
            arguments {
                androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile

                resourcePackageName "com.foo.androidapp"

                // You can set optional annotation processing options here, like these commented options:
                // logLevel 'INFO'
                // logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nice, that got it working.  Thanks!  One question, did you notice that the build process & run command took significantly longer?  Like from 5 seconds to 60 seconds.

Comment: Hmm... I use AA a lot, almost all my classes use the annotations, however the app(s) atm aren't that big. What is annoying however that I often have to "refresh gradle" so the BlahAcitivty_ gets generated.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the library path to your build.gradle file in that particular Module of your Android Studio project

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

basically you have to make sure the dependencies in your libs folder are actually being compiled

I'm not sure about the underline dilemma

Comment: the libs folder is included by default

Comment: @bluedevil2k did you add `classpath ‘com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+’w` as detailed  in the comments here , http://www.jayway.com/2014/02/21/androidannotations-setup-in-android-studio/  it looks like there are more and more additional semantical things to add to the build.gradle file as time goes on with newer versions of Android Studio and IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

If you had a problem with "Activity Not Found".
you just need to sync Gradle by Tools->Android->Sync Project with Gradle files.